# IE Autofill Problems with JSF

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf

In my JSF application,  I have input fields that take in numbers. And ajax renders to add this number to a total. This all works fine.

However, while doing testing multiple times. The IE Autofill would suggest the same numbers I have been using.

Now, wanting to save time I use them and notice that the total doesn't change.

I was curious if anyone else has had this problem, and if so; how did they fix it?

P.S. I emulate IE7 compat mode through my servlet being sent with the header

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with old browsers where they do not fire any events when they autofill the forms.

See also:

[How to bind to browser change of input field? (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685146/how-to-bind-to-browser-change-of-input-field-jquery/)

There are some workarounds mentioned here:

- http://avernet.blogspot.com/2010/11/autocomplete-and-javascript-change.html

See which one suits you better maybe turning off autocomplete on that specific input that needs a change event.